# Focus event not firing from textbox using CKEditor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

I am using the ckeditor for showing the formatted text.I am using Asp.net mvc 3 razor helper method Html.CKEditorFor(x=>x.Description) for the above purpose.I need to implement the
watermark feature in this ckeditor.I am using the following code for the purpose,

```
    $("#Description").focus(function() {

    $(this).filter(function() {

        // We only want this to apply if there's not
        // something actually entered
        return $(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == "Type here"

    }).removeClass("watermarkOn").val("");

});
```

But the focus event did not fire when i focus the ckeditor textbox.So i inspected the document using firebug and found the default text is rendered inside the following class('cke_show_borders') generated by mvc ckeditor helper.So i modified the above code to

```
    $(".cke_show_borders").focus(function() {
    $(this).filter(function() {

        // We only want this to apply if there's not
        // something actually entered
        return $(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == "Type here"

    }).removeClass("watermarkOn").val("");

});
```

But still the focus event is not firing.
Where i am going wrong pls help its urgent.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that you should try to do this using *their* API instead of jQuery. Have you checked out their [developer features](http://ckeditor.com/developer-features)?

Incidentally, I've seen people change CKEditor's default behavior using something like:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor');
editor.on('instanceReady', function(e) {
    // customize stuff here
    // this.document.$.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].style.styleName = 'value';
    editor.focus();
});
```

Similarly, you could modify their onfocus event like so:

```
editor.on('focus', function(e) {
    // code here
});
```

Comment: HI i implemented the above code but landed with the following error on mozilla firefox console.Error: uncaught exception: [CKEDITOR.editor.replace] The element with id or name "ckeditor" was not found.

Comment: Oh, yeah you will have to change 'ckeditor' to whatever `id` you gave to _your_ `textarea` tag.

Comment: Hi all the things have been kept in the document ready function and  the focus event gets fired when the above way is followed but the problem is i am not able to remove the class(watermarkOn) applied on the ckeditor when return statement returns true.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my following //code.$(document).ready(function () {
//        var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('Description');
//        editor.on('focus', function (e) {
//            $(this).filter(function () {
//                var description = "@Model.Description";
//                return $(this).val() == description;
//            }).removeClass("watermarkOn").val("");
//        });}); I can assure you that the following statement returns true//return $(this).val() == description;

Comment: Not sure what "@Model.Description" is but other than that it looked ok I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have placed this code in a `$(document).ready` handler to ensure that the DOM is fully loaded before trying to subscribe to any events:

```
$(function() {
    $('.cke_show_borders').focus(function() {
        $(this).filter(function() {
            // We only want this to apply if there's not
            // something actually entered
            return $(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == 'Type here';
        }).removeClass('watermarkOn').val('');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Hi all the thins has been kept in the document ready function.